# netcat script send message while running

Tags: linux, bash, netcat

So I need to create a netcat script that sends a string while netcat to another device is running.

This is by far my code:

```
#!/bin/bash              
recvmess= nc -4 -l 60001 
read $recvmess           
if [ $recvmess == 'Uf' ] 
then                     
        printf 'ta'      

fi
```

I want to connect over a dynamic Port since those are open.
The device I want to establish a connection with netcat has it's own firmware and isn't programmable (You can only change a few settings)

The Device attached to the one i want to connect has two messages: `Uf` and `o.`
I want to read data of it. So I need to send a `ta` after an `Uf` to receive the devie information.

When I am on my server and establish a connection with `nc -4 -l 60001` I receive incoming messages. What I want to do is, that if an `Uf` is received the script should write a `ta` and send it to the device so that I get the information.

It would be nice if you could help me. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I did a little workaround for it and now it works. The code is below:

`nc -k -4 -l 60001 < colas.txt` and for colas.txt: `ta`

Now it's sending the `ta` string on the beginning of the communication and I get my information I need.

Comment: See [Netcat TCP Programming with Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27590835/4154375).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help me with my problem. First is, that I don't really understand the linked code and second the only thing it does I also can achieve with the command `nc -4 -l 60001`. With the linked code I can't send any `ta` manually but with my command I can do this. So it doesn't help me with my problem

Comment: if `nc -k -4 -l 60001 < colas.txt` works, so would `echo ta | nc -k -4 -l 60001` if you want to avoid having to handle a file

Comment: I also tried `echo ta | nc -k -4 -l 60001` but for some strange reason I can't explain it doesn't work as expected. I won't receive any messages from my device when casting this command.