# redirect the ouput of command into a socket on linux

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, io-redirection, netcat

I'm using netcat to connect to a server.
the problem is that i want to send somme non printable to the server caracters.
I wanted to achieve this with a command redirection in linux.
lets say this is the command: `nc hostname port`
so when i checked the file descriptors of the command nc in the folder: `cd /proc/$(pidof nc)/fd` is saw the there was another fd with number 3 that conserns the socket. `3 -> socket:[1675643]`
the problem is that i wanted to redirect the output of let's say `echo -ne '\xff\x0f\xab\xde' > ./3` to the socket.
I couldn't do so and the ouput is: `bash: ./3: No such device or address`

Comment: What about `echo -ne '\xff\x0f\xab\xde' | nc hostname port` ?

Comment: no i can't do so, because i dont know what to give as input to the hostname before the connection is established, because after that it will print a msg with an adresse that i'm gonna use to exploit a buffer overflow, it's part of a challenge. so before the hostname shares this adress with me i can't figure out what to give as input

Comment: See [Netcat TCP Programming with Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27590835/4154375).

Comment: consider using `expect` tool.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot output something to a socket which is opened only by another process.

In order to first use interactive input/output and afterwards send the echo string, you can do:

`(cat; echo -ne '\xff\x0f\xab\xde')|nc hostname port`

(press the EOF character <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to end your input and start the `echo`).